# Lead conversion permissions issue

Tags: permissions

I have a little issue when some of my users convert leads (I'm an admin in the org). A standard user isn't able to convert their leads that merge with existing accounts because existing accounts (made automatically by a workflow process that I created from a web form) get automatically assigned to me. Long story short, since I am higher in the Salesforce hierarchy, it prevents the regular user from doing the conversion merge. Can I create an exception somewhere or just assign all new accounts elsewhere?

Comment: What is the org wide settings for Accounts? Do you have any sharing rules in place?

Comment: Good call - I changed the Accounts to Public Read/Write. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the org wide default settings for the Account object, or alternatively add a sharing rule that grants access.

More information on org wide defaults:

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en
- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_about.htm&language=en_US

More information on sharing rules:

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&language=en

Specifically Accounts:

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_rules_create_account.htm&language=en_US