# Users unable to convert leads - insufficient privileges

Tags: lead-conversion, error-messages, insufficient-privileges

When my sales users open a Lead record and press the "Convert" button they get the following message:

> **Insufficient Privileges:**
>   *You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or
>   your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see
>   Insufficient Privileges Errors.*

I made sure their profile has the following:

“Create”
 **AND**
 “Edit”
 on leads, accounts, contacts, and opportunities
**AND**
“Convert Leads”
**AND**
“Read”
 on any related campaigns

There is no related campaign. The users are able to create leads, accounts, and contacts. OWD is private for those objects, but Public for Campaigns. I enabled all record types to the user.

Please advise what I need to do to solve this issue and allow my sales user to convert Lead records?

Comment: check this post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94429/lead-conversion-permissions-issue

Comment: have you overridden the Convert button with a VF page (and said VF page not available to running user's profile)?